# SharePoint 2013 Custom Date Refiner

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-search

Does anyone have any experience or recommendation in creating a custom search refiner that allows users to select from month/year values rather than date ranges provided in the default display templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this we ended up created a couple of calculated fields in the underlying libraries that extracted the month and year from the date field as as string. This was then mapped to a managed property and used as a refiner in the search portal.